# Trying to Compile 64-bit DLL with mingw-w64

Tags: dll, compilation, 64-bit, ada, mingw-w64

I've been trying to compile a 64-bit version of an Ada dll using mingw-w64 for use in a C++ program.

It appears to be working, in that it compiles without error and will load into 64-bit programs and I can get the address of the interface functions with GetProcAddress.

However, when trying to call these functions, they break in unusual places with access violation errors. Looking into the pointers, it looks like they're all 0x00000000########, meaning, none of them have any bits outside the usual 32-bit addressing set.

Looking into the ads files generated by gnatbind, I also find:

```
  type Version_32 is mod 2 ** 32;
   u00001 : constant Version_32 := 16#65712768#;
```

This seems to indicate, to me, that even though it's compiling parts of the dll in 64-bit (enough to fool the compiler and program into believing the dll is 64-bit enough to load it), the underlying implementation is still coming out as 32-bit. I'm guessing that's what's causing the access violation errors, accessing 32-bit memory addresses when the program's expecting 64-bit addressing.

How can I get mingw-w64 to actually compile AND bind a dll in 64-bit properly?

Comment: I have no problem building and using DLLs in mingw-w64 successfully, so perhaps it is something wrong with the code you are compiling (e.g. perhaps the code has always included non-portable constructs such as casting pointers to `int` but the problem has not shown up until you try a 64-bit build).    Looks like you have a bit of a debugging project ahead of you but to get help here you will need to try to produce a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: So, just for clarification's sake: when you're compiling a 64-bit dll, does your bind-generated .ads file include similar code? Or would yours show something like "Version_64 is mod 2 ** 64"?

Co-worker, upon debugging, thinks the problem may lie within Interfaces.C.Strings as he was able to get a version running by cutting out some of that code.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you call DLL adainit and adafinal. Or else you need to use [gnatbind -a](http://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/building_executable_programs_with_gnat.html#switches-for-gnatbind) key. In GPR it looks like:

```
   package Binder is
      for Default_Switches ("Ada") use
        ("-a");         -- call adainit from DllMain
   end Binder;
```

Try using MinGW64 from MSYS2. [Some people state that it's best free toolchain for Win64](http://www.ada-ru.org/start). TDM-GCC doesn't have libgnarl built dynamically or something like this.